# Preventing error 503 on JQuery load

Tags: javascript, jquery, error-handling

This is my code on shoutbox update :

```
function updateShoutbox(){
    $("#shoutdiv").load("shoutbox.php", { 'action': 'update' } , 
    function (responseText, textStatus, req) {
        if (textStatus == "error") {
          return false;
        }
    });
}

        
$(document).ready(function(){
updateShoutbox();
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
updateShoutbox();
$("#shoutdiv").scrollTop($("#shoutdiv")[0].scrollHeight);
}, 6000);
```

It returns error each some minutes  :

> shoutbox.php returned error:
>
> Service Unavailable

Is there anyway to handle this error and hide it somehow ?

I edited my code so to stop showing any error on shoutbox update, but it still shows this error each minutes.

Comment: Instead of doing a `setInterval()`, why don't you just re-run `updateShoutbox()` from within the callback handler for your `$.load()`?

Comment: @JaredFarrish you think that's the problem ?

Comment: What shoutbox are you using? A google search of it brings up a few.

Comment: If you have access to the shoutbox.php code, could you provide the relevant code from there as well?

Comment: @bobthyasian I wrote my own ! and this message is freaking me out.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I wrote it OOP , so the shoutbox.php calls a function on shoutbox class to read from a text file.

Comment: @MacTaylor If you are using a custom shoutbox, how are we supposed to help you if we don't know the code? There's a plethora of things that could be causing your error.

Comment: To me the most likely problem seems to be an error in the php thread causing the page to be (temporarily) unavailable as you claim it responds with a 503 Code.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts and question how to hide this random javascript error

Comment: @MacTaylor It's not a Javascript error, it's a PHP error. And it will continue to throw random 503's unless you do something about the server script you made as well.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Why are you AT-ing me?

Comment: @bobthyasian - Oops, for some reason I thought you were the OP. Sorry.

Comment: @MacTaylor - I updated my answer with code that I think will work (although I'm wondering if you took out the part that puts the response on the page after success?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so let's take this for example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    (function iterate(i) {
        if (!!i) {
            console.log('iteration #', i--);

            setTimeout(function next(){
                iterate(i);
            }, 1000);
        }
    })(10);
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/6C8yp/

If you look at the console, you'll see it counts down until `i` is equal to `0`, or `i` is not given (that's what the `!!` is for there). What I'm doing here is looping each second, but only after the last loop has finished. I'm feeding my loop.

Looking at what you have here, I might do this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function($){
    var $shoutbox = $("#shoutdiv"),
        timer;

    (function update(){
        var opts = {
            url: 'shoutbox.php',
            action: 'update',
            complete: wait
        };

        $.ajax(opts);

        function wait(res, status, req){
            if (status == 200) {
                $shoutbox
                    .append(res)
                    .scrollTop($shoutbox[0].scrollHeight);

                timer = setTimeout(update, 6000);
            }
        }

    })();
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/whsPn/

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/whsPn/1/

Ok, so what we have above should mostly emulate the code you have in the question. You'll note that I have the `complete: wait` part in there, and the `setTimeout()` is in that callback. And.. it's only called if the `status` returned is `200` (success).

Now, there you could turn `complete: wait` to `success: wait`, and take out the `status == 200` if statement altogether. Of course, if you *do* want to run the update again, but maybe do something different, this is your chance.

Also note, in the fiddle linked I've got some dummy code in there. So don't just copy/page what's in the fiddle, or you'll have errors and it won't run at all.

**EDIT**: Oops, found an error with `url =`. Fixed.

Comment: That's great code, actually, and the built-in `success` option seems to be exactly what MacTaylor needs, but there's one problem. The shoutbox doesn't update immediately when the page loads, it updates 60 seconds after the page loads. Of course that's a quick fix but I thought I'd point that out.

Comment: You're right; also, that's six seconds. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Haha, 6 seconds, my bad. That's probably not as big of a deal now that you point that out, but oh well.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - There was a couple of things wrong. I got a working version with fiddle now, though. I had to invert my original `wait()` and `update()` function order.

Comment: Fancy! And now that I think about it, you wouldn't need to update on a 302 anyway, so nice catch!

Comment: @JaredFarrish something is wrong and I can't make it work , it doesn't load !

Comment: @MacTaylor - Do you have a link?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to "hide" your error instead of looking for the cause of the error in the first place, try this in your callback function in the $.load:

```
function (responseText, textStatus, req) {
  if(req.status!=200&&req.status!=302) {
    return false;
  }
  //update the shoutbox
}
```

At least to me this is what seems to be the most reliable way to prevent random errors from getting through your checks.

Comment: As I said, you'll have to supply your PHP to get rid of the error itself. The other answer will only prevent it from disrupting the shoutbox is all.